# how to pass the control from interceptor to spring bean in struts2 application

Tags: spring, struts2

I am trying to execute a interceptor to check whether a application is down or up based on a flag from  backend.For this i have written a interceptor and configured in struts.xml and verified with static content....as part of this i need to make a db call to find a particular flag of app_down, for this i have written struts service and dao classes and injected through spring as per existing pattern.But my doubt is how can I connect interceptor and dao class ..how do i configure this..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your service and dao classes the same way you did it through spring. Use a configuration setting `struts.objectFactory=spring`. Another way is to use a helper class that you can use to statically access your service and dao classes from other beans. Which method you prefer is up to you.

Comment: ..how to redirect to a jsp based on the result returned from interceptor.is it possible?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it using [Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or read how to ask a question [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @Roaman C..i have raised a new question..can you please comment on that